# swift parse query how to get first createdAt for each username?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

How can i get First rows of createdAt for each username?

for example: backend looks like this

```
objectId-   username - photo   -  createdAt

5135Aer    -   name1      - image   -  2015-08-21

R35AAA     -   name6      - image   -  2015-08-21

G7356W     -   name3      - image   -  2015-08-20

E355B      -   name1      - image   -  2015-08-20
```

So i want the query will take all rows and skip name1 which is createdAt 2015-08-20 last one because this old row i just want new createdAt rows only for each user.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "test")
        query.whereKey("receivers", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                self.createdAtArray = objects!
                print(objects!.count)
```

I've tried this query but it will take old createdAt and i just want new createdAt for each user , And yes i have set `limit to = 1` , but it will show last record not for each user! It just show one result.

Comment: what are you trying to do ?, so are you trying to create new data only for each user right

Comment: @Lamar I want like to get last users updates like showing their last image , message, etc , I don't want their names to be duplicate i just want first row of createdAt for each user. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So each 20 minutes from now I ask to give the recent object, so if you want query images after 50 minutes or more just change the value for timestamp.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "test")
query.whereKey("receivers", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
 query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
 var timeStamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -1200)
 query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo: timeStamp)
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
if error == nil
{
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
    {

        for one in objects
        {
            var Getimage = one["image"] as! PFFile
             Getimage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                var image = UIImage(data: data!)
                // you have the image now
                createdAtArray.addObject(image!)

            })

          }
      }
  }

 }
```

**Second Option : To get the last object from parse use **getFirstObject method**

```
 func secondQuery(arraydetails:NSMutableArray){
   var query = PFQuery(className: "")
  query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
  query.limit = 1
  query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil
    {
        var detail = object?.objectForKey("text") as! String
         arraydetails.addObject(detail)
    }

   }

  }
```

Comment: thanks, But I don't want like this the usernames duplicated, I just want one row for each username i don't want it to be duplicate and i don't want timer, i just want first createdAt for each user without duplicate, please can you help with that?

Comment: so did you trying this code ... what did it give you back ?

Comment: I've tried it, I got duplicated names! Is there anyway to get First createdAt for each user without duplicate please? There's a column which hold names for example : name1 - message hello, name1 - message bye , so i want to get first createdAt row for users

Comment: I wanted to know if it was working ... So in the **for in loop** create an objectid variable like **var objectID = one.objectId** then create and if and else statement to see if the objectID is not equal to itself ... **if objectID != objectID** so inside of that if statement add the image retrieval code**

Comment: each row has different objectid, please take look at this picture: http://cut.by/bp693

Comment: So you use the username of the uploader

Comment: how can i get the sender value instead of objectId ? can you edit your answer and show me please?

Comment: Var sender = one["sender"] as! String then do if sender != sender

Comment: I did if sender != sender {//nothing working here} else {//this working} so i put print("test") in sender not equal to sender but not showing up, if i type print in else it will be showing! what should i do ?

Comment: Is there anyway to remove found names from query objects? or what do you think?

Comment: no please help i've posted same question please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149883/swift-parse-query-get-last-createdat-objects

Comment: so what is the problem you are having

Comment: I don't want timer as you did, because it will disappear soon and names duplicated, I just want in my view controller to show Last message sent from sender and getting the last row of createdAt to show it up!

Comment: I don't want one result, I want to show all senders without duplicate, but i'll try this

Comment: you said you want to latest my friend so the query has to be 1... And don't forget to vote the answer lol

Comment: I didn't, Read the subject I want Last object createdAt for each username, so in view controller will show, name1,name2,name3 with their last message sent, without duplicate names with old messages

Comment: I don't know how to use that func, is this showing me all objects for each user or just one ? and how can i use it? should i type secondQuery() in viewdidappear or where should i put this ?

Comment: no just took the code out of the function and do whatever you want it

Comment: I did, i got error : Use of unresolved Identifier 'arraydetails' , Is this will show me only one object ? or it will take all user objects ??

Comment: this was an array that i used you don't need to use it

Comment: I think this isn't what i want if this gonna show me only one object, I want to get all Last objects of usernames by createdAt, please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149883/swift-parse-query-get-last-createdat-objects

Comment: because the **query.limit = 1** just comment that part of the code

Comment: i'm getting errors i don't know how to use this query, Could you show me how to make it in viewwillappear , and get "sender" and "photo" columns in arrays?

Comment: just look at the first code and make it similar to the second code that is

Comment: keep getting errors, Could you please update your answer and show me how to get "sender" and "photo" columns and add them to arrays? i'm so sleepy now its 2:50 AM i'm about to sleep, i'll wait your code before i go to bed.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! i have to sleep now, i'll work on it tomorrow, thank you so much again

Comment: I tried your Second option code, Its just give me 1 result and its last object created that's right but i want to get one result for each user in same time like if there 3 names i will get their last object only, like which last message each user has sent to me ?

Comment: I already did that and raise it to 5, isn't working getFirstObject only show one result, any idea ?