# swift parse query get last createdAt objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have did a lot of querys, searched in websites , And already asked this question before and i didn't found a good answer!

I have Parse backend looks like this:
[image]

In my view controller I just want to show Last createdAt for each sender
i want to get all the row of last object for sender:.

so we should ignore "name1: Hello" and "name2: Really when was.." because this old rows we already got new objects.

I want one result for each sender depends on createdAt

so can I get help with query to do this? or how can we do that?

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "test")
        query.whereKey("receivers", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                // now what? I've done everything i could none worked fine
```

I hope if i'll get a help to do that, So please help me if you could.

Comment: wouldn't you just take the first item from the array that comes back? (first check that the length is greater than zero.)

Comment: @JoeBlow Hello, Could you show me example with codes please?

Comment: Add a pointer from the user to the last message they sent.

Comment: @Wain Hello, Could you show me how can i do that? i'm kinda new for these stuff

Comment: @Wain do you mean to make new column in backend which include FALSE or TRUE ? and set TRUE for last message sent ? if yes, what about if there was alot of messages it will take time to send a message? and take long time to change old messages to false ?

Answer (score 1):

you can just add a `limit` to the query.. see parse docs..

```
 let query = PFQuery(className: "test")
    query.whereKey("receivers", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.limit = 1
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
```

Comment: Hello, This will only give me one result! I want one result for each different username, So if there was 3 users i will get 3 results

Answer (score 0):

Your data model isn't really suitable for doing this operation quickly. But, how you setup your data model is dictated by all of your requirements, not just one.

To make this easy you should add a pointer from your `User` to your `Message`, and every time a message is sent by a user you set that pointer (which replaces the old pointer).

Now, you can simply query `User`s, using `includeKey` to get the message, and display your list.

Comment: hi, I don't know how to make the pointer from user to message, Can you show me example on how to do it  please? i'll appreciate it

Comment: And what about if there a column which is have names they're only who receive the message? I want to take last message sent to me not to others

Comment: Which is exactly why I said the data model needs to be driven by all reqyirements. For that you should have another class with pointers to each user and to the last message each sent to the other. Check the parse docs for how pointers work.